# How to make a section scroll between sections, and within another section scroll only it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags, sections

Well, what I need is so complex for me that I can't even explain what I want.

I have a main section, where I need this main section to scroll between the main sections.

Inside the first main section I have another section and I need it to scroll independently of the main section, i.e. only this section scrolls.

Can anyone help me with this?

```js
const prevBtn = document.getElementById("prev-btn");
const nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-btn");
const allSection = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
const sections = [];
let count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < allSection.length; i++) {
  let sectionArr = document.getElementById(`section-${i + 1}`);
  sections.push(sectionArr);
}

function next() {
  prevBtn.classList.remove("disabled");
  if (count < allSection.length - 1) {
    sections[count].classList.add("d-none");
    count++;
    console.log(count);
    sections[count].classList.remove("d-none");
  }
  if (count === allSection.length - 1) {
    nextBtn.classList.add("disabled");
  }
}
function prev() {
  nextBtn.classList.remove("disabled");
  if (count !== 0) {
    sections[count].classList.add("d-none");
    count--;
    sections[count].classList.remove("d-none");
  }
  if (count === 0) {
    prevBtn.classList.add("disabled");
  }
}
```

```css
#page-content {
        width:100%;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
    }

    #sect-one, #sect-two {
        width:50%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color:red;


    }

    @media(max-width:768px) {
        #page-content {
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        #sect-one, #sect-two {
            width:100%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Section, prev & next</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7a83d58e46.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button id="prev-btn" class="btn" onclick="prev()">&laquo; Prev</button>
    <button id="next-btn" class="btn" onclick="next()">Next &raquo;</button>
    
    
<section id="section-1" class="container">
<main id='page-content'>
    <section id='sect-one'>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis aut distinctio magni dolorem nobis illum
                perferendis modi tempora inventore quis!</p>
    </section>

    <section id='sect-two'>

    <section id="section-6" class="container">
    <button id="prev-btn" class="btn" onclick="prev()">&laquo; Prev</button>
    <button id="next-btn" class="btn" onclick="next()">Next &raquo;</button>
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis aut distinctio magni dolorem nobis illum
                perferendis modi tempora inventore quis!</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section-7" class="container d-none">
    <button id="prev-btn" class="btn" onclick="prev()">&laquo; Prev</button>
    <button id="next-btn" class="btn" onclick="next()">Next &raquo;</button>
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae iure iste fugit dolor dicta voluptate
                magnam perferendis, beatae, ipsam id placeat magni voluptatem accusamus animi eum officiis atque hic
                temporibus.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section-8" class="container d-none">
    <button id="prev-btn" class="btn" onclick="prev()">&laquo; Prev</button>
    <button id="next-btn" class="btn" onclick="next()">Next &raquo;</button>
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed amet suscipit omnis nisi nesciunt hic
                expedita optio blanditiis, reiciendis fugit tempora distinctio odit cumque! Dolore eos ratione magnam
                ducimus laboriosam natus vel officia, blanditiis illo ullam pariatur, delectus nostrum deleniti.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section-9" class="container d-none">
    <button id="prev-btn" class="btn" onclick="prev()">&laquo; Prev</button>
    <button id="next-btn" class="btn" onclick="next()">Next &raquo;</button>
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed amet suscipit omnis nisi nesciunt hic
                expedita optio blanditiis, reiciendis fugit tempora distinctio odit cumque! Dolore eos ratione magnam
                ducimus laboriosam natus vel officia, blanditiis illo ullam pariatur, delectus nostrum deleniti.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section-10" class="container d-none">
    <button id="prev-btn" class="btn" onclick="prev()">&laquo; Prev</button>
    <button id="next-btn" class="btn" onclick="next()">Next &raquo;</button>
        <h2>Section 5</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed amet suscipit omnis nisi nesciunt hic
                expedita optio blanditiis, reiciendis fugit tempora distinctio odit cumque! Dolore eos ratione magnam
                ducimus laboriosam natus vel officia, blanditiis illo ullam pariatur, delectus nostrum deleniti.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    </section>
</main>
</section>

<section id="section-2" class="container d-none">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae iure iste fugit dolor dicta voluptate
                magnam perferendis, beatae, ipsam id placeat magni voluptatem accusamus animi eum officiis atque hic
                temporibus.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section-3" class="container d-none">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed amet suscipit omnis nisi nesciunt hic
                expedita optio blanditiis, reiciendis fugit tempora distinctio odit cumque! Dolore eos ratione magnam
                ducimus laboriosam natus vel officia, blanditiis illo ullam pariatur, delectus nostrum deleniti.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section-4" class="container d-none">
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed amet suscipit omnis nisi nesciunt hic
                expedita optio blanditiis, reiciendis fugit tempora distinctio odit cumque! Dolore eos ratione magnam
                ducimus laboriosam natus vel officia, blanditiis illo ullam pariatur, delectus nostrum deleniti.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="section-5" class="container d-none">
        <h2>Section 5</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed amet suscipit omnis nisi nesciunt hic
                expedita optio blanditiis, reiciendis fugit tempora distinctio odit cumque! Dolore eos ratione magnam
                ducimus laboriosam natus vel officia, blanditiis illo ullam pariatur, delectus nostrum deleniti.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This [example](https://jsfiddle.net/yrcqbns3/show) tries to duplicate the basic page structure.  Looking at the example, are you asking how to scroll the region mark (C) independent of the page scroll?

Comment: That's more or less it.

Region (C) needs to scroll horizontally with the "prev" and "next" buttons.

Already the region "A" and "D" need to scroll also with the "prev" and "next" button.

Comment: I'm trying to get the result of this page:

Example: https://ge.globo.com/rs/futebol/campeonato-gaucho/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to answer your question based on the information provided.

Comment: but I'm not asking to do the same as the example site, I just want to make the "prev" and "next" work for each section.